# What does this error message mean?

Tags: security

My website is getting too slow. When I checked the journal entries, I found many errors like the following.

> [image: screenshot]

What is it? What are they trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Those are probably bots trying to find security holes to exploit on your server/website.

The best way to prevent them is with firewall and other security measures on your server.  Most control panels have firewalls included but might need a little configuration before they run properly.  Firewalls usually ban IPs depending on their bad behaviour.

This subject is probably off-topic for the Drupal forums but if you want an extra measure blocking IPs within Drupal you can consider using [AutoBan IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoban) here is a [basic setup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261570/automatically-block-user-that-access-wp-login-php/261571).

Comment: Can this be the main source of my poor site performance

Comment: If they have multiple bots running at a very fast pace it can probably bring the server down to its knees if the CPU's are running to full capacity. So I urge you to look into the security of your server and perhaps autoban IP module.

Comment: I have shared hosting, there is no much things to do

Comment: Talk to your provider about the problem and install the module as well, I have had good results with this module.

Comment: I found that all the requests are from 66.249.64.95 ip which is a GoogleBot, normal?

Comment: A googlebot would not misbehave to a point that brings your server to a halt, are you sure there no more bad IPs?  If all you see is Google IPs perhaps they are Google CDN IPs and all visitors IPs are not found.  If this is the case ask your host to expose those IPs back on the request or at least help with a firewall.  I am not server security expert so use with caution and ask more info another on a more appropriate forum.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will investigate further

Comment: `I have shared hosting` there is your source of poor performance.

Answer (score 3):

It's a tentative to detect which software is used to build the site; in the specific, they are trying to understand if the site is built with Visual DataFlex, a forth generation programming language geared towards creating database and client/server type applications. The [.dfr extension](https://filext.com/file-extension/DFR) is used for the Visual DataFlex license file.
It's similar to those attempts to access a URL used from WordPress to understand if the site is built with WordPress.

Once they know what is used to built the site, they can take advantage of specific vulnerabilities to get access to reserved information or cause denial of service.